# How (or where) to build (or download) hg19.map file

Tags: github, bioinformatics

I am starting an analysis with **delly**, for I was reading its manual (https://github.com/dellytools/sansa).

For the copy number variation (CNV) analysis, I bumped into a "strange" file (a mappability file), **hg19.map**.

However, I have no idea of how to make/download it, and I was wondering: have I to build from `hg19.fa`?

Answer (score 0):

[dellytools/delly README](https://github.com/dellytools/delly/blob/master/README.md#read-depth-profiles) mentions:

> You can generate read-depth profiles with delly.
>
> The command to count reads in 10kbp mappable windows and normalize the coverage is:
>
> delly cnv -a -g hg19.fa -m hg19.map input.bam

But it also points out:

> This requires a mappability map which can be downloaded here:
>
> [Mappability Maps](https://gear.embl.de/data/delly/)

Check first if that file is part of those maps.